# Keras-CNN model for sarcasm detection

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to model a CNN with Keras with the following configuration:

Convolution Layer 1:
Kernel Size= 4,5
Feature Map=50

1st Max Pooling=2

Convolution Layer 2:
Kernel Size=3
Feature Map=100

2nd Max Pooling=2

FC layer=100
Softmax output=3

But I'm having truble mapping the variables and understanding how to code it. I've tried looking at examples but the variables have got me confused.

Also, based on the kernel size, which Convnet should be used, 1D or 2D, or does the kernel size have no part in deciding which convnet is to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine in case for pictures the convolutional layer takes a scan device and always scan a small part of the whole picture. The area of each scan overalys with the next scan. The kernel size is then size of your scanner. Thats why in the picture case the kernel size has the dimension of 2. This is a Conv 2D layer. The dimension of your Convolution layer depends on the dimension of your input.

In the picture case you have a input of shape (batch_size, height, width, color). In case you have text you may have: (batch_size, len_of_sentence, letter). As you can see in the later case your input dimension is smaller then in the picture case. Here you need Conv1D layer and the parameter kerne size only has one dimension.
There are also Conv3D layers, which can be used for dealing with moving pictures.

For your question with the right parameters, I think https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable.